# Procedure to clean internal camera lens

Tags: camera, cleaning

I have an HD7 with considerable dust inside the lens which makes the resulting photos from the camera HORRIBLE. I've tried using an air can to hopefully penetrate what cracks let in the dust and clean it off a bit with no luck.

Has anyone tried opening up their device to clean the internal components and documented the procedure?

Comment: Thanks for adding the correct tags. I've yet to gain the street cred to add new tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Warning this will void your warranty

I have never done what you are asking, BUT I have dissembled the HD7 before. My wife dropped hers in water, and I opened it up to help dry it out.

I used [This youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UBCFsMDTGA) to help me take it apart. Don't be fooled. It is a bit hard than it looks, and I remember it requiring a lot of patience. This is **not** for the faint of heart.

Now, like I said above, I never did this to clean the camera lens. In fact, I **DO NOT RECOMMEND** this. However, should you be set on doing it proceed with caution. A little dust on the lens is far better than a broken phone.

Comment: Thanks, good info. I'm going to check to see if this problem is covered by the warranty. If not, I'll hand the phone to my 3 yr old son ;)